# Show sender name from mail headers in Apple Mail

Tags: macos, email, apple-mail

How to configure Apple Mail.app to show name from mail headers "From: " field and not from Contacts.app???

Apple Mail.app shows me always the name from Contacts.app (card is a read only download from global catalog), e.g.:

- "Service Address" front-desk@ourcompany.net

But we have more than one who use this address. And this people configure there clients as follow:

- name: "person1 first last" / address: front-desk@ourcompany.net
- name: "person2 first last" / address: front-desk@ourcompany.net
- name: "person3 first last" / address: front-desk@ourcompany.net

When I look to the mail headers, there are the correct names inside, but in Apple Mail.app the list view shows only "Service Address" front-desk@ourcompany.net. So I'm not able for differing the sender of mail without reading this.

And I do not want to manage a private address card for this address, because the people behind this address are changing all 4-6 weeks! The version I use before has done this correct, is El Captain a downgrade or have I to change to Thunderbird?

Comment: Have you tried asking this on the [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com) site?

Comment: yes, I ask it at AskDifferent too

Comment: no, this depends not on "Smart Addresses"! (this as anticipatory response to the most likely simple answer)